# C# getting json name without knowing them

Tags: c#, json, hash

I have this Json:

```
{
  "objects": {
    "realms/lang/de_DE.lang": {
      "hash": "729b2c09d5c588787b23127eeda2730f9c039194",
      "size": 7784
    },
    "realms/lang/cy_GB.lang": {
      "hash": "7b52463b2df4685d2d82c5d257fd5ec79843d618",
      "size": 7688
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/chicken/step2.ogg": {
      "hash": "bf7fadaf64945f6b31c803d086ac6a652aabef9b",
      "size": 3838
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/dig/gravel3.ogg": {
      "hash": "48f7e1bb098abd36b9760cca27b9d4391a23de26",
      "size": 6905
    },
    "minecraft/lang/uk_UA.lang": {
      "hash": "02ca127554fb1294b473bac256469a0d908ecd86",
      "size": 97299
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/cat/hitt3.ogg": {
      "hash": "3d98b4b7c37a09101da00d8a3078e0acba6558f4",
      "size": 7371
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/horse/zombie/hit3.ogg": {
      "hash": "ad126e435cca94054bf0d616301799a105526cde",
      "size": 7043
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/endermen/portal.ogg": {
      "hash": "7b4b5323ef066caa1ae43cbe66fffd9dfce4ed32",
      "size": 10010
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/random/glass2.ogg": {
      "hash": "87c47bda3645c68f18a49e83cbf06e5302d087ff",
      "size": 7532
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/bat/hurt1.ogg": {
      "hash": "fddba78b2426f8056be081c98fe82e8411a0a5cf",
      "size": 4878
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/ambient/cave/cave9.ogg": {
      "hash": "b463fa47816fe9a5dfe508093150e647403e4db6",
      "size": 27096
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/records/13.ogg": {
      "hash": "9cbed0e40296f68c61090c9b81816061e068a0ec",
      "size": 1071028
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/enderdragon/wings1.ogg": {
      "hash": "5a368ed32b3357e31629451ace57eb30d90e8874",
      "size": 10617
    },
    "minecraft/lang/ast_ES.lang": {
      "hash": "fc2139572f55c973aedc694b8d633f2a4eb0907a",
      "size": 72927
    },
    "realms/lang/ast_ES.lang": {
      "hash": "3f0a1aea8af9451493927ecb8a18997881ad0e2f",
      "size": 7608
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/cow/step3.ogg": {
      "hash": "482919bc631b317422ab44af3938259bea73fe83",
      "size": 7923
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/step/cloth3.ogg": {
      "hash": "9c63f2a3681832dc32d206f6830360bfe94b5bfc",
      "size": 4897
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/endermen/hit2.ogg": {
      "hash": "cf60aefd0b742c3fa15e808c1a0c33aebd534cc5",
      "size": 6491
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/random/eat3.ogg": {
      "hash": "9f2c4bab5ed55f1714fffa223985c81babc8f6c0",
      "size": 5813
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/step/sand5.ogg": {
      "hash": "9fd6d2c633d276b952f2ff2aaa1fa7e5fb5efd2a",
      "size": 5182
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/step/ladder5.ogg": {
      "hash": "e9a1caaddcde79cdac7aa8eabde50d4cfd1bc578",
      "size": 6077
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/music/game/nuance1.ogg": {
      "hash": "cc1a80b6becfc6d6489c069f053d0a8adc71c339",
      "size": 156322
    },
    "minecraft/lang/zh_TW.lang": {
      "hash": "d2f3c9c340a5cfe30fb7e333c81a4d853d9bbddd",
      "size": 68697
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/random/eat1.ogg": {
      "hash": "dfee39084c771182f6b9e7cfb8c8bc4e255747bc",
      "size": 5678
    },
    "minecraft/icons/minecraft.icns": {
      "hash": "991b421dfd401f115241601b2b373140a8d78572",
      "size": 114786
    },
    "minecraft/lang/es_AR.lang": {
      "hash": "e55edae0011215873faeba154c7d89f590ddb748",
      "size": 74392
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/blaze/breathe4.ogg": {
      "hash": "78d544a240d627005aaef6033fd646eafc66fe7a",
      "size": 22054
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/dig/sand4.ogg": {
      "hash": "37afa06f97d58767a1cd1382386db878be1532dd",
      "size": 5491
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
    dynamic json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

Now I'm stuck...
I have two problems: I have to read every name inside objects like

```
realms/lang/de_DE.lang
```

The problem is that i don't know the names and on the internet i just found how to read the values inside dynamic json objects and not how to read the name of it...

The second problem is that on another class i have to process all this data and i need the hashes too. Is it convenient to calculate the hash on the moment for every file(there are 675 files) or to pass the hashes as a return?
I already return a list converted to an array of URL's so i don't know how to return both the URL's and the HASH and then process them.
I add to the namelist the value with a foreach loop:

```
namesList.Add(finalurl);
```

And then i return this:

```
return namesList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create classes for deserialization like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("objects")]
    public IDictionary<string, ObjectValue> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectValue
{
    [JsonProperty("hash")]
    public string Hash { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can get your names like this:

```
MyClass json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(data);
var names = json.Objects.Keys.ToList();
var hash = json.Objects[names[0]].Hash; // Get the hash of the first item
```

Also don't forget to check if `null` and other possible errors (no data etc).

Comment: And what if i want the hash? How can I access it? Var names is an array?

Comment: Apologies @KristianVukusic, I've posted a similar answer with typed keys :-)

Comment: I think it's just perfect. Tomorrow I'll try to adapt it to my code and I'll let you know!

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if you are satisfied ;).

Answer (score 0):

[L.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11127428/681819) provides a good answer.

The json data looks to match this question here from [user3468962](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31084143/681819). The accepted answer is posted in VB, however could provide a useful base.

It would also be useful to return a typed object. In my experience I have always tried to avoid dynamic properties where possiable as they are not type safe and can lead to legacy support issues.

Try...

```
Foo json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(data);
```

...

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Hash { get; set; }
  public long Size { get; set; }
}
```